# Apache 2.4 VHosts with FastCGI and suexec-custom

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, hosts-file, suexec

I have setup at my local machine Ubuntu 22.04 Apache 2.4 with suexec-custom.
In fact, this setup was working from Ubuntu 16 up to this update to 22.04.
I only load some modules, reload some other and suexec was working fine for a test site say it: `/home/test`
After the update I typed some commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-fcgid
sudo apt-get -y install apache2-suexec-custom
# remove or disable libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php
# or
# sudo a2dismod php*
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

and presto typing `localhost/my/test/file` gave my all the result I was expected!
I even tested:

```
//index.php
<?php

echo '<b>';
echo php_sapi_name();
echo '</b><br>';
printf("%s<br>", 'parent of DOCUMENT_ROOT=<b>'.\dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'</b>');
printf("%s<br>", 'DOCUMENT_ROOT=<b>'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'</b>');
printf("%s", 'User=<b>');
system('whoami');
echo '</b>';

/**
 * A front controller redirector.
 */
// ...bla-bla

phpinfo();
```

The expected result was there:

```
cgi-fcgi
parent of DOCUMENT_ROOT=/home/test
DOCUMENT_ROOT=/home/test/public_html/
User=test*
PHP Version 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.10
Linux cent 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023
x86_64
Build Date
Jan 16 2023 15:19:49
Build System
Linux
Server API
CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support
disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path
/etc/php/8.1/cgi
Loaded Configuration File
/home/suexec/test/conf/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/8.1/cgi/conf.d
........
```

I'm not going to describe the details of how I set up suexec-custom:

```
/home/suexec/test/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-wrapper
/home/suexec/test/conf/php.ini
/home/test/public_html
/home/test/...<program dirs & files>
```

The only thing I have to say is when I started to make some modifications on my `/etc/hosts` I lost my suexec: `404 The requested URL was not found on this server`.
My previous hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    localhost.test   localhost.test
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1
ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouter
```

which does not work anymore, I wonder why (?????). Everything is there though!

Before upgrades and for reasons of development I had changed with **success** owner of `test` dir (`sudo chown -R cent:cent /home/test`) along with the vhost file:

```
#000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  ServerAdmin admin@test.com
  DocumentRoot /home/test/
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  SuexecUserGroup cent cent
  <Directory /home/test/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/suexec/test/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-wrapper .php
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/index.php"
    RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/index.php?$1" [NC,NE,L,QSA]
  </Directory>
</IfModule>

  # CPU usage limits 5s 10s
  RLimitCPU 5 10
  # memory limits to 10M 20M
  RLimitMEM 10000000 20000000 
  # limit of forked processes 20 30
  RLimitNPROC 20 30 

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLogFormat connection "[%t] New connection: [%{c}L] [ip: %a]"
  ErrorLogFormat request "[%t] [%{c}L] New request: [%L] [pid %P] %F: %E"
  ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%{c}L] [%L] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: %M"
  ErrorLog /home/test/log/apache_error.log
  CustomLog /home/test/log/apache_access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

That used to be solid.

**Now about what broke it:**
I made a change at `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 test test localhost
```

**What made it work temporarily:**

With a broken suexec I decided to revert back my owner:

```
 sudo chown -R test:test /home/test
# also at vhost file: SuexecUserGroup test test
```

and there it is but at different url (!!!) `test/my/test/file`

**I decided to play with hosts again and bam: 404**

Luckily I recorded a message at `/var/log/apache2/`:

```
[Tue Feb 14 10:52:04.708251 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6335:tid 140549831124864] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Feb 14 10:52:04.819895 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6335:tid 140549831124864] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 14 10:52:04.819953 2023] [core:notice] [pid 6335:tid 140549831124864] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 14 10:52:04.819995 2023] [mpm_event:warn] [pid 6335:tid 140549831124864] AH00488: long lost child came home! (pid 7645)
suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

`/var/log/suexec.log`:

```
[2023-02-14 10:52:10]: uid: (1000/cent) gid: (1000/cent) cmd: php-fcgi-wrapper
[2023-02-14 10:52:10]: cannot open current working directory
```

I can't revert suexec back to normal anymore.
Should I use a vhost file like `test.conf` or `000-default.conf`? Do we need default file anyway?

Do you see errors in my configurations?
Should I kick off pid connected to suexec and make Apache re-create one?
I'm puzzled!

PS: I also plan to test FPM with user rights that means different vhost files - if you know how to do it I can skip suexec altogether!

Comment: I run a test with the same configurations on suexec on my system but with a different user with a similar vhost file - but with "ServerName localhost" - and with an entry at hosts: "127.0.0.1 myuser myuser localhost" and it worked! ... wait my "test" user also works!! If anyone knows how do we trace this system's behavior please let me know! Do we have any debug utility for Apache modules? I'll try that at the vhost file using "LogLevel" directive....

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problems:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get purge suexec-custom
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php
```

then install from start!

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

to suppress that error open `/etc/hosts` and add:

```
# set FQDN from hostname: 
# ip       FQDN      alias
127.0.1.1   cent.machine.com    cent
```

the format is: `[hostname].whatever.you.want [hostname]`

then open or create `/etc/hostname`

```
cent
```

the format is `[hostname]`

About `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` leave it as it is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

***For vhosts under suexec-custom scheme***

Your options are based on how many test sites you want:

- one site with test url `localhost/my/path` or,
- many sites with test url `my-local-url.localhost/my/path`?

***One site with test url `localhost/my/path`***

You have to enter in hosts:

```
# that existed:
127.0.0.1 localhost
# that was added:
127.0.0.1 my-local-url my-local-url   localhost
```

(you loose the ability of multiple local test domains).

Write directive `ServerName` inside vhost with the `localhost` url:

```
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
```

***Many sites with test url `my-local-url.localhost/my/path`***

In the last case, of multiple local domains, writing inside `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 my-local-url
```

is indifferent!

Write directive `ServerName` inside vhost with url the name of the root folder of your site plus localhost:

```
ServerName my-local-url.localhost
ServerAlias my-local-url.localhost
```

Remember: **my-local-url = root folder name or home of web user**

Test by typing:

```
my-local-url.localhost/my/path
```

***What I did wrong***:

1. I loaded `000-default.conf` file where I had added the contents of my vhost file(!) with `ServerName: localhost` so, I thought Apache was resolving to my vhost file whereas it used the default with the correct directive `ServerName`!
2. I added at /etc/hosts wrong entries in the form `localhost.my-local-url` which is easy to debug with a simple(!) `ping my-local-url` and repeated them in my vhost file under directive `ServerName`(!) - of course Apache never reached that file and finally,
3. My directive `DocumentRoot /home/test` was incompatible with my browser url.

The last case is truly interesting with these alternatives:

- leave `DocumentRoot` at **user root** and search for a url of `localhost/public_html/index.php` because there exists the php file or,
- leave `DocumentRoot` at **user root**, modify `RewriteRule "^(.*)" "/public_html/index.php?$1" [NC,NE,L,PT,QSA]` and search for `localhost/index.php` (**preferable**!) or,
- modify `DocumentRoot /home/test/public_html` (the **web root**), leave `RewriteRule` as it is and search for `localhost/index.php` (but you can't add more rules that can pass the handing of media to Apache if that media exist to a directory higher!)

***In place of conclusion***

Debug Apache vhost file by following some steps:

- Enable `LogLevel debug`,
- Disable most vhosts directives to debug especially rewrites
- Enable directives one-by-one and check for errors.

Hope that helps someone!

**If you know a way to debug Apache it would be very helpful!**